# Laravel multiple domain origin CORS

Tags: php, laravel, cors, dingo-api

I want to allow two domains for CORS in my laravel to be able work with it locally and on the server, thus I don't wan't to expose my app to any domain. That is shat I have for now

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200')
//            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://api.example.com')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    }
```

I'm not able to do it neither as I've commented nor as an array

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can define an array of origins you want to allow and then check the incoming request if its one of them:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $allowedOrigins = ['example.com', 'example1.com', 'example2.com'];
    $origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];

    if (in_array($origin, $allowedOrigins)) {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $origin)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: That works, however my Dingo Api become broken when I access my route in browser. It says {"message":"Undefined index: HTTP_ORIGIN","status_code":500}

Comment: @Sergey, strange, maybe you could try `$request->header('host')` or `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` instead of `$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']`?

Comment: @thefallen Do I need to create a new middleware to add this code ?

Comment: @skm yes, that would be the better approach. You could also make it part of the `EncryptCookies` or `VerifyCsrfToken` class if you have the `web` middleware on all of your routes, but a new middleware is what I would recommend.

Comment: where to implement this solution, file path??

Comment: @Kamlesh its a middleware.

Comment: @thefallen Kindly suggest, in which middleware should i add this solution? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @Kamlesh best make a new one called CORS, so its a single purpose and you know what it does.

Comment: Ok, I will try it tonight, thanks @thefallen :)

Answer (score 6):

@thefallen 's answer works for me, also I had the @sergey 's same problem, I solved like this.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

  $allowedOrigins = [env('FRONTEND_ENDPOINT', 'http://localhost:8080'), env('WORDPRESS_ENDPOINT', 'http://localhost'), env('EXTRA_ENDPOINT', 'http://127.0.0.1')];

  if($request->server('HTTP_ORIGIN')){
    if (in_array($request->server('HTTP_ORIGIN'), $allowedOrigins)) {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $request->server('HTTP_ORIGIN'))
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
    }
  }


  return $next($request);

}
```

this way you can also just set the variables in .env file  like this.

```
FRONTEND_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:8080
WORDPRESS_ENDPOINT=http://localhost
EXTRA_ENDPOINT=http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

Comment: Hey man hanks for your answer it helped me. But i noticed you have duplicate lines here. Was it by mistake?            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $request->server('HTTP_ORIGIN'))
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')

Answer (score 2):

You can add into TrustHosts.php Middleware without doing anything extra. and make sure your app is in production mode.

```
// app/Http/Middleware/TrustHosts.php
public function hosts()
{
    return [
        $this->allSubdomainsOfApplicationUrl(),
        'https://www.nexgi.com'
    ];
}
```

The above code is working well in laravel 8.x and if you are running queue or supervisorctl then restart to reflect the changes.

Comment: Didn't work for me in Laravel 8, even after running `php artisan optimize:clear`/

Comment: It only works if your application is in production mode (```APP_ENV=production```)

Answer (score 1):

You could just check what host you are on, and then send out the matching `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` just for that one.

`$request->getHttpHost()` will get you the host name that was used in the request - if you just need to differentiate based on that, we can probably ignore the other stuff that is also part of the origin (protocol, port) here, and simply make this something like

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $origin = $request->getHttpHost() == 'localhost' ?
                    'http://localhost:4200' : 'http://api.example.com';

        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $origin)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    }
```

Of course you can make this more "sophisticated", if you need this for more possible origins (like match the host name against an array of possible values, take protocol and port into account to if necessary), but if you just need these two for now, that should basically do.